# Image get Blurred when display from Sdcard in ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, landscape

I am using this code, to display Image from Sdcard in image view (in Landscape Mode). But the Image lose its quality and it is blurred.

```
     File imgFile = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()); // path of your file

                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                options.inScaled = true;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null,options);
              profileIV.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

ImageView xml file :

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >
```

Comment: If you know about Picasso than you dont need to create bitmap simple use your image path and show your image using Picasso, try this   Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath))).into(imgView);

Comment: @mohit hope picasso will not create Heapsize problem for bigger image

Comment: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Try this dont use options

Comment: @jois yes it can show good image . but would it create heap size problem? with out option?

Comment: it may or many not

Comment: You can use options like this  
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),options)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because even I was having the same problem, you can skip the orientation part

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        //options.inSampleSize = 16;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        int orientation = getExifOrientation(filePath);


        //rotate bitmap
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);
        //create new rotated bitmap
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        ivProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static int getExifOrientation(String filepath) {
    int degree = 0;
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (exif != null) {
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
        if (orientation != -1) {
            // We only recognise a subset of orientation tag values.
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    degree = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    degree = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    degree = 270;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    return degree;
}
```

**Happy Coding**